# I don't get the joke

Tags: documentation, zeromq

In ZMQ messaging library there is large number of patterns derived from a base "Pirate" pattern.  To quote the [documentation](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php%3achapter4#Client-Side-Reliability-Lazy-Pirate-Pattern):

> I like to call the Pirate patterns (you'll eventually get the joke, I
>   hope).

I have a pretty through understanding of the ZMQ architecture, having worked with it over a half dozen projects and couple of years.  Despite this, and reading basically the entire guide, I don't get the joke.

Perhaps there isn't one, but I can't help the itch that I am missing something fairly obvious.  Thanks.

Comment: [Comment from the author](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/issues/431)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about programming.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the docs:

> reliable request-reply (RRR) patterns that I like to call the Pirate patterns

Pirates say 'arrrr!' like RRR, hence pirate patterns.